# List files inside folders in Arcpy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have done the procedure to list shapefiles in an environment but it returns the folder names inside the envirnoment:

```
arcpy.env.workspace  = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\results"
dd= arcpy.ListFiles()
for i in dd:
    print(i)
```

gives:

```
shapesfiles1  
shapefiles2
```

How to print what is inside these folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arcpy.da.Walk()` can do this, [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm)

This would list all files found:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\results"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(datatype="FeatureClass")

for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in walk:
    for filename in file_names:
        print(filename)
```

Or if you want the full path:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\results"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(datatype="FeatureClass")

for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in walk:
    for filename in file_names:
        print(os.path.join(dir_path, filename))
```

Comment: It will only print if files are found, are you using the same path on both?

Comment: Worked great. Do you know much about arcpy because I am preparing another question?I will post in a few minutes

Comment: I've done a fair amount with it, I'll help if I can.

Comment: This is the new question thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784840/make-a-loop-that-will-take-the-same-name-pairs-from-two-folders

Comment: For questions about ArcPy I suspect that you will be better posting at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.