# Make a loop that will take the same name pairs from two folders?

Tags: python, arcpy

One main folder that has one folder named `old` and another called `new`

The old has some folders. The new has a few of these folders with same names and nothing more.

I want to delete the folders of the `old` that are not present in the `new` first and then: make a loop that will take each file -same name -pair, and put it in the
the following line:

```
arcpy.Append_management(["shpfromonefolder.shp", "shpfromsecondfolder.shp"],"NO_TEST")
```

for example: land.shp from one folder with land.shp from the other folder so it will be:

```
arcpy.Append_management(["land.shp", "land.shp"],"NO_TEST")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete folders in `old_path` if they exist do not in `new_path`:

```
import os
import shutil

old_path = r"old file path"
new_path = r"old file path"

for folder in os.listdir(old_path):
    if folder not in os.listdir(new_path):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(old_path, folder))
```

This will find the matching shape files and pass them to `arcpy.Append_management()`:

```
import os
import arcpy

for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace=new_path, datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for filename in file_names:
        new_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
        folder = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(new_file_path))
        old_file_path = os.path.join(old_path, folder, filename)

        if os.path.exists(old_file_path):
            arcpy.Append_management(inputs=[new_file_path], target=old_file_path, schema_type="NO_TEST")
```

Comment: delete the folders that are **not** present in the new folder. so the old will have the same folders as the new.

Comment: that was a typo in my explanation, the code does remove folders in the old directory if they do not exist in the new directory
`if folder not in os.listdir(new_path):`

Comment: the first part works great. The second gives` Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 11, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 4250, in Append     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Target Dataset: Dataset NO_TEST does not exist or is not supported`

Comment: sorry I'd missed the target dataset from `arcpy.Append_management()` change
`arcpy.Append_management([old_file_path, new_file_path], "NO_TEST")` to `arcpy.Append_management([old_file_path, new_file_path], "your target path", "NO_TEST")` setting the correct target path

Comment: That seems to be the problem but is this the the way i should do it? I mean by reading what i am trying to do isn't supposed to be: `arcpy.Append_management([new_file_path], old_file_path, "NO_TEST")` ? I want to append the new shapefile to the old (which is empty).

Comment: Ah I was going off the example code in your question which had both the old and new paths as inputs. You are correct the `old_file_path` is your target parameter. I've updated the answer with named parameters to make it easier to read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177809/discussion-between-ozzy-and-user10207146).